# Having error in android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0] /home/shubham/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/782dd1b43e0016afc3d7d0a4252da9e3/firebase-auth-19.2.0/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.auth" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Comment: As the error says, make your projects `minSdkVersion` at least 16 (yours is 15). Becuase one library you are using requires it to be at least 16. Much better, in 2020, make it 19 (pretty enough) or 20

Answer (score 0):

In your application modules' `build.gradle`; change minSdkVersion to at least 16.

Like so:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

com.google.firebase.auth  min 16  ,your project min is 15,you should change         minSdkVersion  to 16.the bad way to solve it is to your mainfest,it can be run but may be error when run